# awk onliner script to search files under a dir for 2 strings

Tags: string, unix, search, command-line, awk

I need to search for files which has string str1 appearing before string str2. both strings are in separate lines.

for example,
file1 looks like:

```
abc
def
str1
ghi
str2
```

file2 looks like:

```
abc
str2
def
ghi
str1
pqe
```

My search should return file1.

It should be a one liner script I can run on command line on unix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an one-liner but you can delete the newlines and the problem is solved :)

```
for file in $(ls) ; do
  awk "/str1/{found=1}/str2/{if(found) print \"$file\"}" $file
done
```

What does it do: for each file listed by `ls`, if `str1` appears in it, the script marks it in a variable `found`:

```
/str1/{found=1}
```

then, when `str2` appears in a line, it verifies if `found` is set. If so, prints the file name:

```
/str2/{
    if (found) 
        print "$file"
}
```

**EDIT**: there is still a more concise way to solve your problem, using `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -print0 -maxdepth 1 | \
    xargs -0 -I{} awk '/str1/{found=1}/str2/{if(found) print "{}"}' "{}"
```

It is safer, too, because it handles files with spaces in their names. Also, you can extend it to search in subdirectories just removing the `-maxdepth 1` option. Note that the `awk` script was not changed.

(There always is a good solution using `find` and `xargs` but this solution is always a bit hard to find :D )

HTH!

Comment: useless use of `ls`. Use shell expansion

Comment: @ghostdog74 you are right. Fortunately, the second solution already solves this problem, too.

Comment: @brandizzi: the second approach finds a file eveif str2 comes before str1. which is not what it should do. BTW, in first solution, instead of "ls" in current dir, how can I look into all dirs below current dir?

Comment: I am trying                                                         find . -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} awk '/str1/{found=1}/str2/{if(found) print "{}"}' "{}"                                                  But it returns file name if str2 comes before str1.

Comment: @hari: Both my sed and awk command are finding str2 AFTER str1 and that's why not printing file2 in both cases. However the awk command that ghostdog74 has provided is much more compact than my verbose one.

Comment: @hari: are you getting ths problem yet? It work here. However, if a file has `str2`, then `str1` and `str2` again, it will be listed as well. Is this the problem?

Comment: @hari: do you mean to search _only_ in directories below or _also_ in directories below? If it is the second case, just replace `$(ls)` by `$(find .)` If you want to look only on files _exactly_ one directory below, replace `$(ls)` by `$(find . -depth 2)`; if you to look for files in _all_ directories below, use `$(find . -mindepth 2)`. `find` is a wonderful tool, I'd say :)

Answer (score 3):

So, here is your `awk` one liner

```
awk -vRS="\0777" '/str1.*str2/{print FILENAME}' file*
```

Comment: @ghostdog...does this imply `RS="\0777"` record separator is New line?what does this exactly do?

Comment: this means slurping the whole file in (as a whole string). so finding str1 before str2 would print the filename

Comment: +1 from me .This is a new thing i have learnt.Thanks ghostdog

Comment: @zombie, no problem. actually `RS="\0"` should do the same thing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sed 1 liner for above:

```
F="file1" && test ! -z $(sed -n '/str1/,/str2/{/^str2$/p;}' "$F") && echo "$F"

F="file2" && test ! -z $(sed -n '/str1/,/str2/{/^str2$/p;}' "$F") && echo "$F"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
file1
```

### And here is awk one liner

```
F="file1" && awk '{if ($0 == "str1") {a=NR} else if ($0 == "str2" && a> 0 && a<NR) {print FILENAME} }' $F

F="file2" && awk '{if ($0 == "str1") {a=NR} else if ($0 == "str2" && a> 0 && a<NR) {print FILENAME} }' $F
```

#### OUTPUT

```
file1
```

Comment: you can use `FILENAME` instead of passing `$F` as a variable into `awk`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about `FILENAME`.